# How to save data in C# ASP.NET MVC without using database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, repository

I am developing an application with ASP.NET MVC using Visual Studio 2017 applying the Code First approach. I have three classes (tables) in the model and one repository named `DataBase` and an interface `IDataBase`.

I'm trying to store data in memory without using db. I don't now how to add new item in table?

This is my `DataBase` class (repository):

```
public class DataBase : IDataBase
{   
    private List<Proveedor> proveedors;
    private List<Factura> facturas;
    private List<FacturadeArticulo> facturadeArticulos;

    public DataBase()
    {
         this.proveedors = new List<Proveedor>();
         this.facturas = new List<Factura>();
         this.facturadeArticulos = new List<FacturadeArticulo>();
    }

    public Proveedor AddProveedor(Proveedor item)
    {
        // acces db
        if (item == null)  
        {  
            throw new ArgumentNullException("item");  
        }  

        proveedors.Add(item);  
        return item; 
   }
}
```

My interface `IDataBase`:

```
public interface IDatabase
{
    Proveedor Add(Proveedor item);
}
```

My controller

```
public ActionResult Create(Proveedor provedor)
{
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here
            var data = this.db.Add(provedor);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
}
```

I don't now how to implement Add method and save data in memory without using database.

Comment: If you save data in memory, it will go away whenever IIS recycles your server process.  You need a database.

Comment: Try http://www.litedb.org/, same code first approach, free and your data is actually saved.

Comment: It looks like you have lists of objects, are those where you want to save your data?  It also looks like you're calling `.Add()` to add elements to those lists.  So what exactly isn't working?

Comment: Method in DataBase (repository) isn't working. When I try to create new item I don't have any error, but my Proveedor is empty. I'm using library Unity

Comment: Maybe it's empty because the model isn't binding correctly?

Comment: Save it to a json file?

Answer (score 0):

Just for the case, the Entity Framework is not designed for using In-Memory storage.

To do this, you need to implement the appropriate ADO.NET provider: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/data-providers

Answer (score 0):

```
  /**You can Save Data in XML file**/

  //You can Save and load time by this method but it's slow process,
   it may crash if data is large and system is slow, it stores data runtime
   so takes RAM, its ok to use for few rows without any problem

  //use the collection for storing data runtime
    List<Person> pers = new List<Person>();
    public class Person
    {
      public string id { get; set; }//1
      public string name { get; set; }//2
      public string bilno { get; set; }//3
      public string mob { get; set; }//4
      public DateTime dt { get; set; }//5
    }  


    string path=@"c:\.....";
    void save()
    {
        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        xdoc.Load(path + @"\data.xml");
        XmlNode xnode = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("Items");
        xnode.RemoveAll();

        foreach (Person i in pers)
        {
            XmlNode xtop = xdoc.CreateElement("Item");

            XmlNode x1 = xdoc.CreateElement("a");
            XmlNode x2 = xdoc.CreateElement("b");
            XmlNode x3 = xdoc.CreateElement("c");
            XmlNode x4 = xdoc.CreateElement("d");
            XmlNode x5 = xdoc.CreateElement("e");


            x1.InnerText = i.id;
            x2.InnerText = i.name;
            x3.InnerText = i.bilno;
            x4.InnerText = i.mob;
            x5.InnerText = i.dt.ToFileTime().ToString();

            xtop.AppendChild(x1);
            xtop.AppendChild(x2);
            xtop.AppendChild(x3);
            xtop.AppendChild(x4);
            xtop.AppendChild(x5);

            xdoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xtop);
        }
        xdoc.Save(path + @"\data.xml");
    }
    void load()
    {
        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        xdoc.Load(path + @"\data.xml");
        foreach (XmlNode xnode in xdoc.SelectNodes("Items/Item"))
        {
            Person p = new Person();
            p.id = xnode.SelectSingleNode("a").InnerText;
            p.name = xnode.SelectSingleNode("b").InnerText;
            p.bilno = xnode.SelectSingleNode("c").InnerText;
            p.mob = xnode.SelectSingleNode("d").InnerText;
            p.dt = DateTime.FromFileTime(Convert.ToInt64(xnode.SelectSingleNode("e").InnerText));

        }
    }
```